# Can not define a function type in C

Tags: c, dll, typedef

It just confused me:

`typedef bool(*pGetNameByPid)(DWORD PID, TCHAR lpszProcessName[MAX_PATH]);`

Is there anything with the sentence above? I want to export an function named `GetNameByPid` from an DLL written in C++. But the compile reports that:

`error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'`

Any help?

Comment: BTW, `TCHAR lpszProcessName[MAX_PATH]` can be misleading; it's completely equivalent to `TCHAR* lpszProcessName`.

Comment: Thanks~ I've changed it to the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `bool` type in C89, which is the C standard that the Microsoft Compilers support. You could use an `int` or WINAPI's `BOOL` as the return type:

```
typedef BOOL (*pGetNameByPid)(DWORD PID, TCHAR lpszProcessName[MAX_PATH]);
```

To export a function from DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL GetNameByPid(DWORD PID, TCHAR* lpszProcessName)
{
    /* Do some work */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Great! That's the answer. Thanks!